# Exclude a group regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I search in many threads in Stackoverflow but I didn't find anything relevant for my case.

Here is the source text :

```
<span class="red"><span>70</span><span style="display:none">1</span><span>,89</span> € TTC<br /></span>
```

I want to extract 70,89 with a regular expression.

So I tried :

```
<span class="red"><span>([0-9]+)(<\/span><span style="display:none">1<\/span><span>)(,[0-9]+)<\/span>
```

which returns an array (with preg_match_all in PHP) with 3 groups :

1/ 70

2/

```
</span><span style="display:none">1</span><span>
```

3/ ,89

I would like to exclude group 2 and merge 1 & 3.

So I also tried :

```
<span class="red"><span>([0-9]+)(?:<\/span><span style="display:none">1<\/span><span>)(,[0-9]+)<\/span>
```

but it returns :

1. 70
2. ,89

How can I merge the two groups ?

Thanks a lot for your answers, I am going to be crazy searching for this regular expression ! :)

Have a good day !

Comment: With the last array, you could simply `implode('', $matches)` to get the string "70,89", if that's really what you want...

Comment: Just concanate first array value and second array value, May be like this : `$res = $match[0].$match[1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match the numbers that are wrapped with a plain `<span>`:

```
$str = '<span class="red"><span>70</span><span style="display:none">1</span><span>,89</span> € TTC<br /></span>';

if (preg_match_all('#<span>([,\d]+)</span>#', $str, $matches)) {
    echo join('', $matches[1]);
}
// output: 70,89
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers ! But what I would like, it's only one match with the regular expression, without use concatenation (or join) in PHP. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user2219905 That's not possible, because the numbers are separated from each other by pieces of HTML.